# c++ passing subclass as parameter

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance

I got a superclass named Obje

```
#ifndef OBJE_H
#define OBJE_H

#include <QString>

class Obje
{
    public:
    Obje();
    QString name="";
    int id;
    int itemid=0;
    void setItemid(int i);
    virtual void update(){};
};

#endif // OBJE_H
```

and I got a subclass named Npc

```
#ifndef NPC_H
#define NPC_H

#include "obje.h"
#include "QString"
#include "QPixmap"
class Npc : public Obje
{
public:

    Npc(QString dir="left");
    QString direction="left";

    QPixmap* spriteSheet = nullptr;
    QPixmap face;
    QPixmap sprites[3];
    void update(int nid);
    QPixmap* getCurrentSprite();
    int currentFrame;
    QString frameDirection;

};

#endif // NPC_H
```

I also got a class to manage listWidgets

```
class ListUpdate
{
public:
    ListUpdate();
    static void update(QListWidget *q, vector<Obje>& i);

    private:
    static struct item{
        QString id;
        QString name;
        QPixmap px;
    };

    static QListWidgetItem* newItem(ListUpdate::item &i, int c);
};

#endif // LISTUPDATE_H
```

When I try to pass object named "npcs" which is type vector"Npc" to ListUpdate::update , it gives this error
Passing the vector:

```
ListUpdate::update(ui->listWidget,npcs);
```

error:

```
C:\Qt Projects\RpgEditor\npcscreen.cpp:64: error: C2665: 'ListUpdate::update': none of the 3 overloads could convert all the argument types
```

Note: I also got 2 other overload functions and I didn't write them here to prevent unnecessary confusion(that's why it says , "none of the 3 overloads")

Why doesn't it accept my subclass ?

Comment: Can you please provide the definition for `npcs`?

Comment: Is your npcs of type std::vector<Npc> ?

Comment: yeah, It didn't show < > , I was trying to fix that by editing

Comment: and yes , it's type std::vector<Npc>

Comment: Use getters and setters rather than member variables

Comment: where is your virtual dtor in the base class?

Comment: yep , I know but I'm not planning to make it opensource or a group project. I'm just trying to build this editor so I can use it for my actual project. I just didn't want to extend the coding process

Comment: what is virtual dtor?

Comment: @OzanDeniz See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors) for information on virtual destructors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationship between a *base* class and a *derived* class does not extend to containers (except for a few special cases). `std::vector<Npc>` is not convertible to `std::vector<Obje>`. Perhaps you can template the `update` method like this :

```
template<class T>
static void update(QListWidget *q, vector<T>& i);
```

This solution will work for vectors of any type that matches the expected interface of `Obje` including, but not limited to, types that publicly derive from `Obje`.

Comment: Ohh I see, I suspected using a container was the problem. Unfortunately I don't know using templates but perhaps I should study that. Thanks